# Alternates to using a Config File for holding server connection details

Tags: python, config

I am currently creating a test framework for the Automated testing of a number of backend components. I am writing the framework in Python.

Up until now I have been holding the connection details (IP Address, Port, username, password etc) in a config file and retrieving the details from here these details are fluid and can change depending from test run to test run dependant on what is being tested and where. However this config file is now becoming large and difficult to manage.

Before I start splitting the config file into smaller more manageable files which are easier to maintain I wanted to know if there is an alternative to storing this kind of information that I could try.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution might be Apache ZooKeeper. It is easy to setup, maintain and manage. Take a look on this.
https://zookeeper.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

If the config file is getting so big that you think about splitting it up, you could think about transfering it into a sqlite db and do the spliting through tables.